# Получить acces token ВК

Tags: вконтакте, token, authenticationtoken

Хочу сделать бот автопостинга.
Нужно получить разрешение пользователя на отправку сообщения от его имени.

Создал Standalone приложение.

Перехожу по ссылке для получения токена: [https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=IDПриложения&display=page&scope=offline%2Cmessages&redirect_uri=&response_type=token&v=5.80](https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ID%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&display=page&scope=offline%2Cmessages&redirect_uri=&response_type=token&v=5.80)

Нажимаю разрешить в ответ получаю это:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"This application has no right to use messages"}

Подскажите, что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Доступ к сообщениям имеют только официальные приложения. Используй токен VKMe, ибо из scope убирай 'messages'.